# Change property AFTER animate() has finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to take the text "Hey, I'm matt." and rebound it off the page, then change it to "Matt lastName" once not visible, and then rebound back in a different location after the change.

jQuery

```
$('#about').click(function() {
    $('a#name').animate({'left' : '52%'});
    $('a#name').animate({'left' : '-53%'});
    /*$('a#name').animate({'text' : 'Matt lastName'}); -- doesnt work */
    $('a#name').animate({'top': '60px' });
    $('a#name').animate({'left' : '20px'});
    $('a#name').animate({'left' : '-=10px'});

     });
```

If I use ("a#name").css("text","Matt lastName"); the text change right when I make my click. Is there a way to have the .cc wait for the previous animate calls to complete before running?

Comment: `$('#yourElement').animate({...}, function() { // on complete })` http://api.jquery.com/animate/ read it carefully it's all there

Comment: [animate docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), animate takes an optional complete callback that gets called once animation is done

Answer (score 3):

Hi if you need to know when the .animate complete use this syntax

```
$('a#name').animate({'left' : '52%'}, function() {
// Animation complete.
});
```

or if you want set a duration

```
$('a#name').animate({'left' : '52%'}, duration, function() {
// Animation complete.
});
```

Comment: what is the //animate complete call?

Comment: That function is the callback function, which is great if you need to queue things up. Alternatively, you can simply queue them `.animate({}).animate({})` etc.

Comment: //animate complete is a comment i set to tell you where to put the script you want to run when animation complet

Comment: @MattEm `what is the //animate complete call` .... read the documents that several people already gave you links to!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change text when element is outside of the viewport. For this use complete callback of the [`$.fn.animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method:

```js
$('#about').click(function () {
    $('a#name')
    .animate({left: '52%'})
    .animate({left: '-53%'}, function() {
        $(this).text('Matt lastName');
    })
    .animate({top: '60px', left: '20px'})
    .animate({left: '-=10px'});
});
```

```css
#name {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="about">About</button>
<a id="name">Hey, I'm matt.</a>
```

It's also better to chain `animate` methods so that you don't requery DOM for `a#name` element, a little performance improvement.

Comment: Thanks dfsq! Saved me on two issues in 2 days ;)